# Struggling to make nested anchor same size as parent line item

Tags: css

I'm working on a Wordpress site and am not fully following the html and css given to me.

I have a rule that says when a menu item is hovered, make the background of the line item orange and the nested anchor text white:

```
.dropdown > ul li:hover, .dropdown ul li.current_page_item {
background-color: rgba(255,165,0,0.4);
```

Then:

```
.dropdown ul li a, .dropdown ul a { // because there are nested drop down menus
display: block;}
```

The first rule works the second does not. Using the inspect element feature I notice that when I apply this rule it becomes scored out. When I apply the rule `outline: solid 1px` to see the nested anchor, it is indeed smaller than the parent line item when my goal is to make it match the size.

Here is the nav: http://jsfiddle.net/hfnjgjxf/

Notice that when you hover over the menu items the text only changes to white when you hover over the center (the inner `a` tag). The inner `a` tag should be the same size as the parent so that when hovered, the text turns to white, on any part of the line item.

Hope I'm talking sense. If you view the fiddle you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the list items don't have explicit `width` and/or `height`, we can't change the size of anchor tags properly to fill entire space of each list.

However, you could simply achieve that by adding the padding on anchor tags instead of the list items:

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/hfnjgjxf/1/)**

```css
.dropdown ul li {
    /* padding: 7px 10px; */ /* Remove this declaration */
    border: none;
    border-right:2px solid lightblue;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.dropdown ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 7px 10px; /* Add this instead */
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I just updated the stylesheet and that has solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

It would not be required in this situation to make the anchor element the same size as its parent, but just to apply the effect to the anchor, based on the hover of the parent li. You can achieve that by changing the selector to match the `li` hover rather than the `a` hover.

```
.dropdown > ul li:hover > a {
    color: white;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hfnjgjxf/2/

Comment: Oh. That's useful to know too I may have gone that route if I knew earlier